# How to consume a web service using .NET Core 2.0 Connected Services

Tags: web-services, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a service called GetReportService.  My endpoint is http://xxx1/usa/report.asmx.  I am using POST passing a parameter id123.

How do I invoke this web service using a web api in .NET Core 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the connected service option is a WCF service so I am able to consume the service as I normally would in previous versions of .NET.

However, in .NET Core if I want to inject that service, I do have to go to the Startup.cs file and add my service in the ConfigureServices method and then inject the service into my controller.

This is a more detailed explanation of what I did:
[How to inject WCF service client in ASP.Net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732319/how-to-inject-wcf-service-client-in-asp-net-core)