# Can I call web forms service from .net core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms

How do I call method of .net web forms service from .net core application?

Comment: I dont think they are compatible with each other. Perhaps, you can have two projects - one dot net core, another web forms in a single solution and they can talk to each other. but within a single project, I dont think so. if you are looking to build a UI for your .net core app there are far better options like Blazor, React, Vue and Vanilla JS.

Comment: I am just guessing, hence, posting this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: What's your mean about web forms service, does it represent .asmx file？If you want to connect to .asmx file from core api, have a reference for:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996467/how-to-consume-a-web-service-using-net-core-2-0-connected-services

Comment: @Yongqing Yu No, it is not .asmx file. I want to call controller's method (.cs class).

Comment: @Jay Those are two separated projects.

Comment: then, you should put some code. are you asking for an entire guide on how to do it? Show us what you have done, and put the error that you get please :)

Comment: I am asking for guide. I tried to add 'WCF Web Service Reference' in .net core project, but it gave me an error message: ''Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 0):

> I want to call controller's method (.cs class).

You have two ways to achieve it.

First, you can register an IHttpClientFactory and use it to configure and create `HttpClient` instances in your .net core application.

More details, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Another way is using `ajax` to make get or post request to controller's method in js.