# How to inject single instance of WCF service client in ASP.Net core using the code generated by dotnet-svcutil?

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.1, svcutil.exe

**Context:**

We migrated our application to ASP.Net Core 2.1 and got everything "working" but ran into performance issues under heavy load. After doing much googling, I found this [article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and then [this one](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/05/03/httpclient-factories-in-net-core-2-1/) which advocated for using a single instance of `HttpClient`. Since we connect to several WCF services and we're injecting them using `AddScoped` I figured that maybe we need to do the same for our WCF clients.

This is how we're injecting the WCF service client in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddScoped<IWCFService>(s => 
  new WCFServiceClient(
    binding, 
    new EndpointAddress(Configuration[$"ServiceEndPoints:WCFUrl"])
));
```

The [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39732412/2097243), that I found, of injecting WCF client proxies also use `AddScoped` so I might be going down a rabbit hole with this.

We also copy/pasted the generated client proxies because VisualStudio was a bit buggy in the "ConnectedServices" area but I've since got that working. I don't think that that was my performance issue but I suppose it could be.

**Question(s):**

Is the `dotnet-svcutil` generated "client" the same as the `HttpClient`? I don't think it is but maybe it's susceptible to the same resource bottlenecks and should be treated the same? And if that is the case, how does one inject a single instance of the "client" into the generated proxy code? The available constructors don't take anything like that.

Example constructors:

```
    public WCFServiceClient() : 
            base(WCFServiceClient.GetDefaultBinding(), WCFServiceClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.CustomBinding_IWCFService.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }

    public WCFServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
            base(WCFServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), WCFServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }

    public WCFServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(WCFServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }

    public WCFServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(WCFServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }

    public WCFServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Having a singleton WCF client is almost certainly a bad idea.  If one of your requests results in the client becoming faulted then nothing works as I do not believe you can recover a faulted client.

Comment: I would suggest you do some more analysis of your performance issues and provide some details.  One possible solution if you are not already doing it, call the wcf services asynchronously however without details of your issues its hard to tell.

Comment: Also you might check you are releasing the clients as soon as possible to take advantage of the underlying connection pooling i.e. do not rely on the garbage collector by calling Close/Abort explicitely as required