# How to consume an existing web service in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to consume a web service and display the data to the user. Earlier, date was retrieve from data using stored procedure, so for that I had created API controller in ASP.NET Core MVC and made an ajax call using the route defined in controller.

But in this case there is already a web services so I assume I do not have to create a API controller but not sure how can I achieve this.

Comment: What kind of a web service are you trying to consume?

Comment: If you use WCF service,you can see [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732319/how-to-inject-wcf-service-client-in-asp-net-core).

Answer (score 0):

It's in json format. A web API.